# Upload changed file with same name does not actually upload new file

Tags: autodesk-forge

I need to upload changed file with same name and changes are not visible on viewer.
I saw similar posts ([UploadObject - revisions to the file don't seem to count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089716/uploadobject-revisions-to-the-file-dont-seem-to-count)) and solutions (https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/i-make-changes-and-nothing-happens) but no one does actually work.
I also try with cleared browser cache, with adding x-ads-force but it always display old file.
How to solve this, please?

Answer (score 0):

x-ads-force: true should work. To make sure files are different, try uploading the file in different buckets with different names and see in the viewer, you can use oss-manager.autodesk.io for a quick check.